# login the browser into google with php (zend gdata)

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata-api

I was using the *private share link* for viewing a calendar inside my users personal page, but now google decided to change things https://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=1631300

Say I have a user's password and username.
I can login to a Google account and add events or stuff using Zend Framework, but how can I login to Google and make the browser logged in (inject a cookie or something, as if the user went to gmail, he is already logged in).

This way the user would see his own calendar and won't be getting any warnings.

**UPDATE**

how can i show the calendar(even read only would be ok too) in an iframe if i have user/password of his gmail(or google) account

Comment: For god's sake ppl. It's Zend Framework, Zend is a company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the user has either shared the calendar or made it public. Google is trying to harden their security. The method you were using allowed you to access a user's private calendars. This is clearly undesirable behavior. The Google Data Protocol api supports several authentication methods. The paage [HERE](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/GettingStarted.html) is meant to help you choose which is right for your application. The api docs reccomend using oauth to authenticate, and the site [http://oauth.net/](http://oauth.net/code) offers several libraries for accessing the API from PHP. OpenID is also a supported option, as well as a hybrid which is meant to streamline the process by taking advantage of both OAuth and OpenID.

As far as displaying the calendar in an IFrame, just create an html page that Retrieves the atom feed for your calendar and displays the events as html. As it is XML any XML handling method you like will work (i.e. XSLT, simpleXML, etc.,) Then Use the url of this page as the source attribute of your iframe.

Here is an example using the ZEND gata library:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Example List of calendar contents</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      // load library
      require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
      Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
      Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
      Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
      Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');

      // create authenticated HTTP client for Calendar service
      $gcal = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
      $user = "username@gmail.com";
      $pass = "pass";
      $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $gcal);
      $gcal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);

      // generate query to get event list
      $query = $gcal->newEventQuery();
      $query->setUser('default');
      $query->setVisibility('private');
      $query->setProjection('basic');

      // get and parse calendar feed
      // print output
      try { $feed = $gcal->getCalendarEventFeed($query); } 
      catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) { echo "Error: " . $e->getResponse(); }
    ?>
    <h1><?php echo $feed->title; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $feed->totalResults; ?> event(s) found.<p/>
    <ol>
      <?php        
        foreach ($feed as $event) 
        {
          echo "<li>\n";
          echo "<h2>" . stripslashes($event->title) . "</h2>\n";
          echo stripslashes($event->summary) . " <br/>\n";
          echo "</li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
      ?>
    </ol>

  </body>
</html>
```

The URL of this file is the source of your IFrame.
Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: thanks! but can i inject these events in some javascript calendar in order to present the user with some google like calendar? otherwise it's kind of useless for me

Comment: You can display it however you want. Thia simple example just lists the results, but you can make the display as fancy as you want.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot write cookie outside your domain because of cross-site policy.

The simplest thing you can do is require user to login into his Google account. Just like here at Stackoverflow, if you're using it with Google account, user is redirected to Google login page, he grants permissions, and then he's redirected back to your site.

[I think this may be a helpful resource](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html).

Comment: Yes, use open authentication. The user logs in to your site with his Google ID and you don't have such trouble.

Comment: can't i automate this for the user, this is an internal website and asking the user to login everytime is not acceptable...

Comment: Google's cookie has a quite long expire date afaik. And that means next time user will try to use your app, he'll get logged in automatically.